# Problems which matlab is good for

Tags: matlab

Let me ask whether using Matlab for my particular problem is nonsense or some people do the similar.

I have an initial sequence `S(1)`, where each term is a 2D point.
I create a new sequence `S(2)` by inserting a new term point `p` 
between each consecutive 2 term points `p(i)` and `p(i+1)`.
Where `p` is a function `f` of 4 term points of nearest indices on `S(2)`. 
Namely,

```
p= f( p(i-1),p(i),p(i+1),p(i+2) )
```

And the function `f` is written in a C like style 
but not in the pure style of matrix language. 
In the same way , I repeat generating the new longer sequence `S(i+1)` up to `S(m)`.

The above may be vague for you, but please give some advice.
I do not ask whether Matlab is the best choice for the problem , but whether no expert will use Matlab for such a problem or some will.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It heavily depends on `f`. If `f` could be coded efficiently in Matlab or you are willing to spend the time to MEX it (Matlab C extension), then Matlab will perform efficiently.

The code could be vectorized like this:

```
f = @(x) mean(x,3);
m=3;
S{1}=[1,2,3;4,5,6];
for i=2:m
    S{i} = cat(3,...
        [[0;0] S{i-1}(:,1:end-2)],...
        S{i-1}(:,1:end-1),...
        S{i-1}(:,2:end),...
        [S{i-1}(:,3:end) [0;0]]);
    S{i} = [f(S{i}) [0;0]];
    S{i} = cat(3,S{i-1},S{i});
    S{i} = permute(S{i},[1 3 2]);
    S{i} = S{i}(:,:);
    S{i}(:,end)=[];
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Matlab seems to be suitable for such a task. For the data structure of your list of sequences, consider using [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/f16-42340.html#f16-6840). You could have `S` as a cell array, and `S{1}` would correspond to your `S(1)`, and could again be a cell array of points, or a usual matrix if points are just pairs or triples of numbers.

As an alternative, Python in my opinion is particulary strong when it comes to all kind of sequences.